# Как объявить кнопки в отдельной функции а потом вызвать в другой?

Tags: python, telebot

Пишу бота на библиотеке Telebot в Python.

Как мне объявлять кнопки в одной функции а выводить в другой?

```
def Keyboard_list(): 
    Keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(True) 
    Key0 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='NULL', callback_data='F1') 
    Key1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='NULL', callback_data='F2') 
    Key2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='NULL', callback_data='F3') 
    Key3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='NULL', callback_data='F4') 
    Key4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='NULL', callback_data='F5') 
    Key5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='NULL', callback_data='F6') 
    Keyboard.add(Key0, Key1, Key2, Key3, Key4, Key5) 
    return Keyboard
```

Comment: Если можно примером)

Comment: Приведите свой код, только токен не показывайте.

Comment: 'def Keyboard_list():
    Keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(True)
    Key0 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='NULL', callback_data='F1')
    Key1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='NULL', callback_data='F2')
    Key2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='NULL', callback_data='F3')
    Key3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='NULL', callback_data='F4')
    Key4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='NULL', callback_data='F5')
    Key5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='NULL', callback_data='F6')
    Keyboard.add(Key0, Key1, Key2, Key3, Key4, Key5)
    return Keyboard' @ViktorIlyenko

Comment: @ViktorIlyenko, как мне теперь вывести кнопки в другой функции? Заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Делать так:

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Текст, которые выводится перед блоком кнопок", reply_markup=Keyboard_list() )
```